# Moving Shapes With KeyListener In Java

Tags: java, keylistener, shapes

I'm trying to write a program that allows a user to move a shape with arrow keys and change its color with the enter key.  I wasn't taught anything about GUIs or event-based programming, so this is my first experience with any of that.  I think I understand the basics of it, but I'm having trouble just finishing the syntax to make everything run.  The tutorials I find online use timers, which I'm not using.  Here's my current code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab15Panel extends JPanel
{
    Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.blue, Color.green, Color.red, Color.orange, Color.yellow};
    int initialX = 90;
    int initialY = 80;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(colors[0]);


    g.fillRect(initialX, initialY, 100, 100);


    Lab15Key listen = new Lab15Key();

}

private class Lab15Key implements KeyListener
{
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            initialX++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
    {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
    {}
}
```

}

I make my frame in a different class.  Right now I'm unsure of two things:
1. How do I use addKeyListener with the filled shape?  Is there a way to refer to the filled shape?
2. Is my idea of "moving" the shape correct?  That is, creating variables outside of the methods for the position of the shape and then using my KeyEvents to change those numbers?  Or will the shape not be moved in this case? (Note I've only written the code for the up key event.)

Any help you can give me would be appreciated.  I'm definitely a Java novice, and I'm just trying to understand these basic concepts but the resources I have aren't helping.

Comment: Whoops!  I've been messing around with the code so much that I forgot to change that back.  It should read g.fillRect(intialX, initialY, 100, 100);  I just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `KeyListener` to your panel to actually make it listen for key presses. This is known as registering the listener. I would put it in the constructor:

```
public Lab15Panel()
{
    Lab15Key listen = new Lab15Key();
    this.addKeyListener(listen);
}
```

Without this step, you are creating the listener, but it has nobody to tell when it hears something.

If you just want your panel to get repainted each time the key gets pressed, then you could do something like this in your KeyListener:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        initialX++;
    }
    Lab15Panel.this.repaint(); // Calls repaint on the instance of the enclosing class
}
```

Comment: This is also called registering the listener.

Comment: Ah, okay--I was wondering where to actually put that.  Unfortunately my code still doesn't work.  I'm thinking it has something to do with my method of moving the shape by changing the variables, because I think maybe the shape is only being drawn once and has to be redrawn somehow.

Comment: What is it doing now? Are you getting a rectangle? Does pressing the left arrow key cause anything to happen?

Comment: The rectangle shows up (as it always has), but nothing actually changes when I press the key.

Comment: The reason the tutorials you found use timers is so that they can make the panel get repainted periodically. Currently, your panel gets painted once. If you don't want to use timers, I suppose you could just call repaint each time the key gets pressed.

Comment: I appreciate all the help you've given me.  However, I still can't get the rectangle to move.  At this point, I'm not sure what it is--perhaps some nuance elsewhere in my code.  (This probably explains why my professor prefers to use IDEs).

Comment: You should also try the things @MadProgrammer listed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues working against you...

1. You've not registered the `KeyListener` with the component, so it will never receive key events
2. You don't repaint the panel when you change the state of the rectangle, remember, Swing uses a passive painting algorithm, so it only paints the UI when it thinks it needs to. You need to give Swing a nudge by calling `repaint`
3. Your component isn't focusable, meaning that even if you did the other two things, you'd probably still not get it it work.

`KeyListener` is a pain, it will only be triggered of the component it is attached to IS focusable AND HAS focus, generally, you are better off use Key Bindings

See [How to use key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: I appreciate your input.  Unfortunately, I'm restricted to using KeyListener for this assignment.  I don't know anything about focusing.  Is it a simple fix?

Comment: Not really, there are sommanynthings that can steal focus. Start by making the component focusable (setFocusable(true)), use requestFocusInWindow to give the component focus. You might want to attach a MouseListener and use mouseClicked and call requestFocusInWindow

Comment: Do those need to be in the constructor?  I apologize for all these questions... I'm unfamiliar with pretty much everything you just said.